# How to create add method in MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Instead of using add() in controller to add records, I want to create a service and create an add method in it but I'm getting a null reference error in `if (addsolution == null)` part . What am I missing?

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddSolution(HataCozumViewModel solution)
{
    var result = servis.AddSolution(solution);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Service:

```
public HataCozumViewModel AddSolution(HataCozumViewModel psolution)
{
        DBEntities1 hataprojedb = new DBEntities1();
        HataCozum addsolution= hataprojedb.HataCozum.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault();

        if (addsolution== null)
        {
            addsolution.ID= psolution.ID;
            addsolution.HataID = psolution.HataID;
            addsolution.CozulenHataAdi = psolution.CozulenHataAdi;
            addsolution.CozumAciklama = psolution.CozumAciklama;
            addsolution.HatayiCozenKullaniciID = user.ID;
            hataprojedb.HataCozum.Add(addsolution);
            hataprojedb.SaveChanges();
        }

        return psolution;
}
```

View

```
 <form class="form-group" method="post" action="\Home\AddSolution">
        <div>
            <label>Who's solving the error?</label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.HatayiCozenKullaniciID, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.hatayicozenkisi1, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Error Explanation</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CozumAciklama)
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Error ID</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.HataID)
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Error's name</label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CozulenHataAdi, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.hatalist1, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Save Solution</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Could you please your full `servis` details and how you are calling the `servis` on the `controller` class? Are you getting data on `ActionResult AddSolution(HataCozumViewModel solution)`?

Comment: Hello does it resolve your issue? Do you need any further assistance on this?

Comment: I solved it and added my solution , thank you

Comment: Outstanding solution. Keep it up.

Answer (score 1):

**`"What am I missing?"`**

> Your form submit format is not correct please try to modify your
> snippet like below

**View Should Be:**

```cs
    <form class="form-group" method="post" asp-controller="YourControllerName" asp-action="YourActionName">
        <div>
            <label>CozulenHata Adi</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CozulenHataAdi)
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Save Solution</button>
    </form>
```

**Output:**

[image]

> **`Note:`** `action="\Home\AddSolution">` this is not the valid way to write `controller action` name this eventually casuing your `form submit data loss`. Rather you should rewrite that like below:
>
> ```cs
> <form class="form-group" method="post" asp-controller="YourControllerName" asp-action="YourActionName">
> ```

Hope that would resolve your issue and guided you accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing the method like this and now it works. Thank you all for your help

```
  public HataCozumViewModel AddSolution(HataCozumViewModel psolution))
        {

            DBEntities1 hataprojedb = new DBEntities1();
            
            var addsolution= = hataprojedb.HataCozum.AsQueryable().Where(w=>w.ID == psolution.ID).FirstOrDefault();


            if (addsolution== null)
            {
                HataCozum test = new HataCozum();
                
                test.CozulenHataAdi = psolution.CozulenHataAdi;
                test.CozumAciklama = psolution.CozumAciklama;
                test.HatayiCozenKullaniciID = psolution.HatayiCozenKullaniciID;
                hataprojedb.HataCozum.Add(test);
                hataprojedb.SaveChanges();

            }
            return psolution;
```

Comment: Is there anything else that I can help you with?